# Laravel how to validate if exists and belong to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I need to check if the shift_id in the request exists in the database, which can be done by the following

```
'shift_id' => 'required|exists:shifts,id'
```

but how can I also check if this shift_id belongs to the authenticated user

notice that the shifts table has a column named user_id

Comment: So how you Auth your users give more information [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use inline validation by adding the name and value of the column after your first column check Like,

```
'shift_id' => 'required|exists:shifts,id,user_id,'.auth()->user()->id,
```

And If you would like to customize the query executed by the validation rule, you may use the Rule class to define the rule fluently. In this example,

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
 
Validator::make($data, [
    'shift_id' => [
         'required',
          Rule::exists('shifts')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('id', request()->get('shift_id'))->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
          }),
     ],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you bro, I've tried it and it worked